# press a button to a css div block

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website.

I have a div block

```
<div id="table_and_dqinfo" class="table_and_dqinfo">
    <div id="dqdiv" class="dqinfo">
        <h4 class="centertext">Information Pane</h4>
        <div id="dqdiv_volgraph"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`dqdiv_volgraph` is an image block which has the image link.

Instead of putting the div block above into the CSS to show the image directly on the website, I want to put a CSS button, so that only after I press the button, it would open the div block above to show the image on the website.

Could anyone give me some hints about how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what u want?

I used checkbox and label as a button.

When you click on label, it checks the checkbox, then using sibling selector (`+`) of CSS

```
input:checked + #dqdiv_volgraph{
      display:block;
  }
```

I toggle the visibility of the  `#dqdiv_volgraph` div

Feel free to style the `label` tag and make it look like a button according to your project

> Note that the `for` attrib of `label` and `id` of the `input` should
>   be same

```css
input,
#dqdiv_volgraph {
  display: none;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked+#dqdiv_volgraph {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="table_and_dqinfo" class="table_and_dqinfo">
  <div id="dqdiv" class="dqinfo">
    <h4 class="centertext">Information Pane</h4>
    <input id="checkb" type="checkbox">
    <div id="dqdiv_volgraph">
      <h1>Put image here</h1>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200">
    </div>
    <label for="checkb"> Click me</label>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank Gautam Naik for your suggestion. It seems that your code show the images directly, right. I want to show the images after click the "click me" box.

Comment: @DongHui, I dont understand, when u click the button, the bottom div becomes visible

Comment: @DongHui, put ur images inside the div

Comment: @DongHui, check now

Comment: Hi @GautamNaik, sorry to reply you late. Just did a lot of test. Yeah, your method works. Thanks very much for your great help! ;)

Comment: @DongHui If this answer helped you, then please accept it

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could also use JavaScript to solve this particular issue.

```js
function showImage(n) {
    var Images = document.getElementsByClassName("table_and_dqinfo");
    //Get all elements with class "table_and_dqinfo"
    var i = 0;

    if (Images[n].style.display == "block") {
        Images[n].style.display = "none";
        return;
    }
    //Checks to see if the selected Image is already visible. If so it
    //switches it makes it invisible

    for (i = 0; i < Images.length; i++) {
        Images[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    //Make the other Images invisible.

    Images[n].style.display = "block";
    //Change selected Image to visible
}

function showAll() {
    var Images = document.getElementsByClassName("table_and_dqinfo");
    var i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < Images.length; i++) {
        if (Images[i].style.display == "block") {
            Images[i].style.display = "none";
            continue;
        }
        Images[i].style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```css
.table_and_dqinfo {
    display: none;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

.button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="button" onclick="showImage(0)"> Button for Image 1 </span>
<span class="button" onclick="showImage(1)"> Button for Image 2 </span>
<span class="button" onclick="showAll()"> Button to show all Images </span>

<div class="table_and_dqinfo">
    <div>
        <h4>Image 1</h4>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="table_and_dqinfo">
    <div>
        <h4>Image 2</h4>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style the button as you please. You can also put whatever you want inside the `<div class="table_and_dqinfo">`